Use resources.pipeline.pipleine.sourceBranch in stage run condition
I have a multi stage pipeline that has a trigger from another pipeline. If the triggering pipeline is not in the "main" branch I want to skip all prod stages, for example:
  - ${{ if eq(variables.resources.pipeline.ACP_Server_Build.sourceBranch, 'refs/heads/main') }}:
    - stage:....


Is there a way to use the resource sourceBranch in a condition as I described?
If I were using the target pipeline source branch I could do it with the following:
variables:
  - name: isMain
    value: ${{ eq(parameters.branch, 'main') }}

  - ${{ if eq(variables['isMain'], true) }}:
    - stage:....


However the documentation shows that the variable: resources.pipeline.resourceName.sourceBranch is not available as a template variable. If I try to set a variable like this:
  - name: resourceBranch
    value: $(resources.pipeline.resourceName.sourceBranch)


Then $(resourceBranch) is available inside a step but also doesn't work in a template condition. I don't really want to add a condition: to each stage because unlike the root level condition, which simply leaves the skipped stages out of the run, adding the condition on each stage individually results in a lot of "Stage Skipped" items in the deployment.

Hi, the $(resources.pipeline.resourceName.sourceBranch) variable can't be used in template expressions, which are evaluated at pipeline compile time.


I have a multistage pipeline that has a trigger from another pipeline. If the triggering pipeline is not in the "main" branch I want to skip all prod stages.

The $(resources.pipeline.resourceName.sourceBranch) variable can't be used in template expressions, which are evaluated at pipeline compile time.
Workaround
You can create two separate pipelines with different branches in the Resource pipeline completion trigger. By creating two separate pipelines, one for the main branch and one for all other branches, you can control which stages are run based on the source branch of the triggering pipeline.
For example, for your current multistage pipeline with the prod stages, use the following Resource pipeline completion trigger with the main branch. This pipeline is triggered only when the resource pipeline successfully completes a run on the main branch.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: resourceName
    source: resource pipeline
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main

Then copy the yaml of the above pipeline and create a new pipeline.  In this new pipeline, delete the prod stages and change the Resource pipeline completion trigger to exclude the main branch. This pipeline is triggered when the resource pipeline successfully completes a run on any branch other than main.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: resourceName
    source: resource pipeline
    trigger:
      branches:
        exclude:
        - main

By configuring it this way, production stages will only run if the triggering pipeline is on the "main" branch, without resulting in a lot of “Stage Skipped” items in the deployment.


I don't really want to add a condition: to each stage.

I'm afraid you have no other option if you want to use something like:
variables:
  - name: resourceBranch
    value: $(resources.pipeline.resourceName.sourceBranch)

According to Pipeline resource metadata as predefined variables:

In each run, the metadata for a pipeline resource is available to all jobs as the following predefined variables. These variables are available to your pipeline at runtime, and therefore can't be used in template expressions, which are evaluated at pipeline compile time.

resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runURI
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceBranch
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceProvider
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedFor
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedForID


Its not that I want to use the variable that way, it's just a solution I tried. It seems silly to not be able to include the triggering branch in template conditions. Given that the target pipeline will always be running from main, i'm not sure why microsoft wouldn't make that value accessible in the same way the target pipeline variables are.

@user2186028 it's not a matter of wanting or not - some information is just not available at compile time.
